# Saving stack of activities

Tags: android

Lets say: i have Activity A, i go to activity B. Then go to main screen with home button. And I resume the app. Now i have same activity B. Here is my problem: if i want to go back to Activity A i press back button and I'm forced to go to main screen. I think I should save the stack of activities somehow. Can somebody more experienced show me the way ?

Sorry for my English. I tried to explain my problem clearly. Here is that B activity

```
public class RouteActivity extends ActionBar {
    Button find;
    EditText myLocation;
    EditText ObjLoc1;
    EditText ObjLoc2 ;
    EditText ObjLoc3;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.route);

        final LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService( Context.LOCATION_SERVICE );

        if ( !manager.isProviderEnabled( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER ) ) {
            Intent gpsOptionsIntent = new Intent(  
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);  
                startActivity(gpsOptionsIntent);
        }

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent intent = getIntent(); // gaunam
        User user = (User) intent.getSerializableExtra("user");

        myLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routeCurrentLocation);
        ObjLoc1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routeObjectAddress1);
        ObjLoc2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routeObjectAddress2);
        ObjLoc3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.routeObjectAddress3);

        find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.routeSubmit);
        find.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                dosig();

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
    }



}
```

I start my RouteActivity like this

```
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent(
                            "com.project.my.RouteActivity");
                    menuIntent.putExtra("link", realLink);
                    menuIntent.putExtra("user", user);
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
```

Comment: that should be main screen. thanks for noticing

Comment: Where you are starting the ActivityB?

Comment: I think i should save my activities stack somehow, maybe in a bundle ? In result, anytime i get back to B activity from main screen, Activity should know what was the previous activities

Answer (score 0):

for returning to your A Activity you can listen for home button press in your B activity and finish your B Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    switch (keyCode) {
    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME:
      {
        B.this.finish();
        return false;
      }
    }
}

return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: ok, but if i finish B activity after returning to app from main screen, there will be no activities alive anymore

Comment: @user3522865 : you have A Activity in backstack right?

Comment: when i resume my app from main screen, i don't

Comment: @user3522865 : your question is bit unclear to me , you have MainActivity , Activiy A and Activity B? you press home button in Activity B then you want to go to Activity A somehow when you return to your App?i don't know what is Main Screen? if you didn't clear BackStack Backbutton will do the work!

Comment: Main Screen is Home screen

Comment: A have 2 activities. A and B.

Comment: @user3522865 : according to your providing code it's not possible unless you finish() your A activity when you are starting B Activity.when you start B Activity there should be A and B in BackStack so going to home screen doesn't change the Backstack and pressing BackButton should pop your B Activity and returning to A.plz check your code again or provide your full code.

Comment: The code needed is here. I triple-checked my code. I think the main reason it happens is that my activity stack is not saved. I think so because: if i go forward or back to A or B activities without stopping my app (going to Home Screen) everything works fine, but if i go to Home Screen and return to my app, i can't go From B to A activity using back button, because there is no activity alive anymore.